# Автоматический минус ответу при его правке из "Сообщения плохого качества"

Tags: поддержка, голоса-против, очередь-проверок, дух-сообщества

У меня появилось подозрение (основанное на практике), что при внесении правки в ответ ему автоматически ставится "-1" системой, если правка производилась из [проверки "Сообщения плохого качества"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts). Я считаю, что это неправильно - ведь ответ (особенно после правки) может быть вполне хорошим.

Ошибка ли это, или же это нормальная реакция системы, или это всё же совпадения?

Если в предыдущие дни я ещё мог предположить, что это просто совпадения (кто-то заминусовал ответ в ту же минуту, что и я отредактировал пост), то сегодня в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/76241/76685#76685) у меня была возможность убедиться, что "-1" и правка были произведены в одну и ту же секунду. Это не похоже на совпадение, особенно ранним утром по Москве.

Если посмотреть на [историю проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history), то у большинства сообщений, которые были отредактированы, есть минусы. В качестве контрпримера можно привести [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433427/433460#433460), у которого минусов нет. Но вот только что бы это значило?

**UPD**.

Такая же проблема наблюдается и при редактировании из *проверки "Первые сообщения"*: [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425159/#434167).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Пользователь [Community](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile) голосует против сообщения если:

- сообщение получило тревогу "спам";
- сообщение получило тревогу "оскорбительно";
- сообщение получило тревогу "низкого качества", и эта тревога была отмечена полезной.

Тут стоит отметить, что тревога "низкого качества" отмечается полезной:

- вручную модератором;
- автоматически, когда сообщение, отмеченное тревогой, получает правку пользователем (не автором сообщения) из очереди проверки.

В случае "спама" и "оскорблений" сообщение получает голос против:

- как только модератор вручную отмечает тревогу полезной;
- автоматически, по прошествию заданного времени.

Поведение подробно описано в [вопросе на Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/).

Comment: В случае спама или оскорбления, насколько я видел, минус ставится сразу же. В [этом ответе](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/#58035) про это тоже сказано. Именно про автоматический минус при правке сообщения, отмеченного тревогой "низкого качества", я в [упомянутом вопросе](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/) информации не нашел, но, поискав по Meta, что-то подобное в паре вопросов нашел, включая [этот ответ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212871/#215328).

Comment: Но меня вот беспокоит: понятно, почему [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/76241/76685#76685) отметили тревогой "низкого качества", но зачем было отмечать тревогой [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434801/#434818)?

Comment: @Regent К сожалению, логика фильтра сообщений низкого качества достаточна прямолинейна.

Comment: не могу найти источник для ответов: *«автоматически, когда сообщение, отмеченное тревогой, получает правку пользователем (не автором сообщения ) из очереди проверки.»* Формально где-нибудь задокументированы правила когда "дух сообщества" минусы раздаёт?

Answer (score 6):

Интересное наблюдение.

Я тоже считаю, что в таком случае минусовать неправильно. Более того,
(похоже, сейчас в правилах этого нет, а вот раньше (на ХК) такая идея точно озвучивалась)
оценка вопроса на самом деле это его ценность  (даже не его, а всей темы (вопрос + ответы)), если угодно, мера привлекательности.

Оценка, которую мы видим в строке с вопросом должна говорить участникам -- "прочтите **эту тему**, тут ценная информация" (в случае минусов -- наоборот -- "ерунда, можно не заглядывать"), а не только являться оценкой вопрошающего (что сейчас фактически делается) в данной теме.

Comment: По сути, я просто отредактировал ответ, немного улучшив его. Возможно, правка была размером всего в 2-5 символов. А автор ответа сразу получает минус за это... Это, по-моему, за гранью добра и зла. Оценка ответа проводится, если ответ отмечается тревогой - вот там "да", я понимаю, за что минус автоматически ставится.

Comment: Согласен, это очень важный акцент - оценивать не поведение спрашивающего, а ценность темы.

Answer (score 6):

Более того, в данный момент существует баг/эксплоит: можно поставить флаг «плохого качества» и сразу отредактировать сообщение, тогда Дух сообщества поставит ему минус (голос «против»).

Хорошая новость: если в течение часа после этого минуса сообщение получит голос «за», то Дух сообщества отменит свой минус.

Подробнее об этом: [Is this flagging behavior expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305457/2790048)