# Автоматический минус ответу при его правке НЕ из «Сообщения низкого качества»

Tags: дефект

Я прочитал [этот вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/689/227016) и ответы к нему. И всё равно не понял, почему ответ может автоматически получить минус если будет отредактирован **не** из очереди проверок, а обычным образом. А именно, если

- ответ редактируется **не** из очереди проверок
- участники **не** ставили тревоги на ответ
- у участника, редактирующего ответ, есть права на прямое редактирование (минуя очередь предлагаемых правок),

то ответ может автоматически получить минус — [вот ответ, подтверждающий это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/684128/255118) (ссылка откроется только у Модераторов видимо).

В том вопросе есть [замечание о некотором баге](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1241/227016), но это про другое ­— когда участник отмечает ответ тревогой и затем редактирует ответ, здесь же рассматривается случай редактирования ответа **без** отмечания участником ответа тревогой.

Поэтому предлагаю изменить логику автоматического выставления минуса ответу при правке, а именно **никогда** не ставить ответу автоматический минус, если ответ редактируется обычным образом (**не** из очереди проверок).

Comment: Ну это скорее [meta-tag:дефект], чем [meta-tag:предложение].

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov согласен, изменил метку.